# Handling different type of data

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this situation:
**Model.ts:**

```
export interface Foo {
   name: string;
   value: sting;
}
```

**Json:**

```
{
  [{
    "name": "a",
    "value": "1"
    },
    {
    "name": "b",
    "value": "2"
    },
    {
     "name": "c",
     "value": { "different": [ {"x": "bla", "y": "bla", "z": "bla"} ]}
    }
  ]
}
```

until now i was handling this kind of situation with  interfaces or type any. How can i face these one different type? maybe Object.assign?
I'm talking about a different type that i know it might be that type but the problem is that i am using type string in the interface except one case like these one above

Comment: Not sure what the question is. How to type such an object ? How to use it ? Also, Can `value` be any object ? or a specific subset ?

Answer (score 1):

can use many types on a property

```
export interface Foo {
   name: string;
   value: string | your_custom_interface;
}
```

Comment: thanks. and how do i treat these in my typescript? using "instance of"?

Comment: @SteveBl basically yes, there is more info on this here for instance :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546421/how-to-get-a-variable-type-in-typescript