# TypeScript mapping return type of a function from its argument type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write a function whose return type depends on its argument type. Below is what I tried.

```js
type Options = "First" | "Second";

type ArgType<T extends Options> = { type: T } & {
  First: { value: number };
  Second: { value: string };
}[T];

type RetType<T extends Options> = {
  First: number;
  Second: boolean;
}[T];

function f<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> {
  if (arg.type === "First") {
    // T is "First"
    // ArgType<"First"> is { type: "First"} & { value: number }
    // RetType<"First"> is number
    return 23; // Error: Type '23' is not assignable to type '{ First: number; Second: boolean; }[T]'.
  } else {
    // T is "Second"
    // ArgType<"Second"> is { type: "Second" } & { value: string }
    // RetType<"Second"> is boolean
    return false; // Error: Type 'false' is not assignable to type '{ First: number; Second: boolean; }[T]'.
  }
}

// Example usage of function f.
const x = f({ type: "Second", value: "Hello" }); // Type of x correctly inferred as boolean.
const y = f({ type: "First", value: 3 }); // Type of y correctly inferred as number.
```

I get type errors when I try to return from `function f`.

- How can I implement a function of type `<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T>`?

Comment: You are almost there. Just make a dynamic interface for Return type.

Comment: @VidorVistrom may I ask you what is a dynamic interface? A quick google search does not give me any documentation about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771307/typescript-dynamically-create-interface/45777530

Comment: Or easier try this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546421/how-to-get-a-variable-type-in-typescript

Comment: `function f<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> { return { First: 23, Second: false }[arg.type]; }` will work.  Otherwise `if/else` and `switch/case` statements don't play very nicely with generics, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995)

Comment: @jcalz yeah... I found out `switch` statement doesn't help either. Thank you for the insight. I guess there's a long way left until such magic can work. If you can put your workaround as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known pain point in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for discussion.  In the following code:

```
declare const arg: ArgType<"First"> | ArgType<"Second">;
if (arg.type === "First") { 
    // true block
    arg.value.toFixed(); // okay
} else {
    // false block
    arg.value.toLowerCase(); // okay
}
```

the compiler is able to narrow `arg` to `ArgType<"First">` in the true block and to `ArgType<"Second">` in the false block.  That's because `arg` is of a [discriminated union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) type and you're checking a discriminant property.  Control-flow based type narrowing is very useful, but it only works to narrow the type of *values* like `arg`; it does not narrow *type parameters* like `T` in the following code:

```
function fError<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> {
    if (arg.type === "First") {
        // true block
        arg.value.toFixed(); // error
        return 23; // error
    } else {
        // false block
        arg.value.toLowerCase(); // error
        return false; // error
    }
}
```

Here we have similar code, but instead of `arg` being a concrete union type, it's now a type depending on a generic type parameter.  The control-flow narrowing stops working.  Even if the compiler could see that `arg` was an `ArgType<"First">` in the true block and an `ArgType<"Second">` in false other, this still wouldn't do anything to `T`.  And so neither `23` nor `false` would be verified by the compiler to be assignable to `RetType<T>`.  In order for *that* to happen, the compiler would need to narrow `T` to `"First"` in the true block and to `"Second"` in the false block.  This isn't a good thing to do *in general* (what if `T` is actually the full `"First" | "Second"` union?), but the current behavior where the compiler completely gives up is not doing you any good here.

Until any fix comes for this (such as the feature request in [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808)), there are workarounds.

---

The safest one is to actually change the implementation of the function to perform the same indexing operation implied by the `RetType<T>` type:

```
function fIndex<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> {
    return { First: 23, Second: false }[arg.type];
}
```

If you really don't want to pre-calculate the values you're not going to return, you can use [accessors](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) instead.  For values like `23` and `false` it's probably no big deal, but if the results are expensive to calculate or have side effects then getters will give you back something more like the `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` flow:

```
function fIndex2<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> {
    return {
        get First() {
            return 23;
        }, get Second() {
            return false;
        }
    }[arg.type];
}
```

---

In cases where indexing isn't an option, you will have to resort to something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that what you're doing is okay even though it can't verify it:

```
function fAssert<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> {
    if (arg.type === "First") {
        return 23 as RetType<T>;
    } else {
        return false as RetType<T>;
    }
}
```

A similar workaround is to use a single [overload](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) signature that callers can use, while implementing a looser signature:

```
function fOverload<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T>;
function fOverload(arg: ArgType<Options>): RetType<Options> {
    if (arg.type === "First") {
        return 23;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Both the assertion and overload workaround are not as type safe as the indexing version.  They will balk at obviously crazy return types that have nothing to do with `RetType<Options>`:

```
function fBadOverloadCaught<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T>;
function fBadOverloadCaught(arg: ArgType<Options>): RetType<Options> {
    return "whoopsie"; // error, not number | boolean
}
function fBadAssertCaught<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> {
    return "whoopsie" as RetType<T>; // error, not number | boolean
}
```

but they will not catch problems where you're returning the right type in the wrong situation:

```
function fBadOverloadMissed<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T>;
function fBadOverloadMissed(arg: ArgType<Options>): RetType<Options> {
    return (arg.type === "First") ? false : 23; // no error but reversed output
}
function fBadAssertMissed<T extends Options>(arg: ArgType<T>): RetType<T> {
    return ((arg.type === "First") ? false : 23) as RetType<T>; // no error but reversed output
}
```

So you should be careful with this.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFARAMQQCc1gcoAfXAZQgGNUATHAbgFgAoD0SKAQUIDmAFXAQAPEKgQAHsAgoGGOIlRoAfFigBvKNwgAuKJIC+UAGTaOUa1ALFghnQDcAhgBsArgagoPAWwAjCEIoYzZ2GygaegVHKFdPbxJCBBQBUPDjAG0hAF1wrlEoACUIYBFICSlZeUVYeGR0DWwtKxs7EkNfQODwyOjGQwCkJDcIFxRMnPyODgY6NxdCaBiSKCWBQ35hUTF8IhIcDUptivEcAYUj8IQAMygACg2AOj0sTGx9+xwASksImwvBJeV5IAjSCAMB4-ZhQAD0cKgSAA1i4QBxTBA3GhoK0AdYge4QcAkAAZJAAd2CAGEXDjobCEUjUej2MZZuxbh4ULQVCgoLcAEIuBhVGRyBRKBqqNRPQRbQRnCRqH6GUrlXZCDR4yJ3R4vN4fT4dUh-HWRQGCZ7AiCg8GQhnwxHBQhIQhtC1QZbADyEfkAJgAzIznYRXe78aEpNjcR6LYTEqDyVTCLT6TCnVIw2645Fvb7+bd3DiQ1nw3H2WyOVyeXyBQBJBQyMU1SX1PnqOWbPiKzUqtVlJVa-55soF7S2A4OKBBgA0UTogwFxeg2QNohmVc425rvMaDab0n9LYldWUjU7GwVO0qWtVJUHfZHNnzfufnoEZUn9mh789L7HN8gz6f9jHnT9gAXGIoTNXN-1fQsVxAz1K0iNcrT0TdKw4Xc61uXg0BxQhgBPWopQ7WUrx7G9xDvAcNVvbU4z1LtXiKI1cBNX4-1HH0gMDdYMHVIc1GQqMsRxHiAL4xCY0Eh8GNo0SKwxKwcO5PdUAFGAnGCNwkBFUi23PGUu2vET72Evtwlw-dbh0vSDKhKjTl2Eymksx9Knc9Q-xY9ceA4r5DlgyNePHYCK2jSTzU9BDlxjMTK2wzkNLw4UGAcwh9JFWkPAEAALEjJHFMj2wvSj5Woiz6JEmy0rsjKspyhg8sK4AzOqtzpQ82ruoov94pwCkCpGMA0AQCAWEzF03XnFAkEg7oghCShhlGcYUFU1La0akUCKI4A2qKoyzx6y8qtcxjPMU5VBsA-lhtGpBxsmsg6QUuqZuzQh5sWnx-BWigoHWsYJm29Tdq0oURWapyAFkEEIyFTvIirOqupSbrqyHNMLJrdOyhGkZxZzLt7bzzv7T7+oq+6ZP1DD2I+Tip24gB+BLJMMYDMwWss3RBjxIOWQnSaRYWwGF7bbOhjKDuCYBEeR0UStbM6KIximsb6xj6fHB5WMNFngtNKBOaLOSecDP4PqsxjS352aQgCYWvQgMXIQl4ApeACHt1WSDpE0W5G3maQHh0PRDAuRcrnnG0Y4ACSxfSyGMDMmTOJF7mD+gwzoYA3BAKBUluF0vY+0HNueDhA6gEvsFDw9I90UQY64hOiW8ASM9LbOkHuEv8+WXli9LlBy4Lhh5OW4JniAA)

Comment: Your indexed getter pattern is amazing. Thank you