# Argument type restriction in TS function declaration

Tags: typescript

I came across some function declaration like below.

```js
type DataType = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC;

function Func(data: DataType): data is TypeA {
...
}
```

I don't understand the `is` part of the declaration. How it affects the return type of the function?

Comment: It's a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

Comment: Also relevant: [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14425568) [How to get a variable type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35546421) [Typescript: Check “typeof” against custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51528780)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript) might help you understand the `is` keyword a little better.