# How to determine is a variable BehaviorSubject or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs

I have a variable which can have type of `Date` or `BehaviorSubject<Date | null>`. I wanna know how can i check if the variable is a `BehaviorSubject` or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a variable type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546421/how-to-get-a-variable-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this in JavaScript you can do:

```
const behaviorSubject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject();
const isBehaviorSubject = behaviorSubject instanceof Rx.BehaviorSubject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following

```
class BehaviorSubject {}
let myVariable = new BehaviorSubject()
console.log(myVariable instanceof BehaviorSubject)
```

Comment: if you run ```console.log(typeof myVariable)``` it will log ```Object```

Comment: I have fixed my suggestion. Please recheck

Comment: This is specific to rxjs, so creating your own class `BehaviorSubject` doesn't help.

Comment: I added a class example so that the entire code works. I saw that you have got the answer you were looking for :)